# How To Root An Android Phone?

Tags: rooting

I was looking here and there and i can't find any answers how to root my samsung galaxy s6 i was trying to root fully i was trying kingoroot,iroot,kingroot i can't so i find a different way to root my phone i just plug my computer and just download some files and show those steps that how to root a android phone? it says you need to root but a way to root the way is to enable bootloader so i have no option in my settings now guys how i will root my phone guys help me out of this thing!

Answer (score 0):

Every phone is rooted diferently. It depends on the phone and current ROM installed. Normally the steps are as follows:

1. Enable USB debugging in the developer options for your phone. Sometimes the bootloader is also unlocked from the developer options.
2. Unlock the boot loader.
3. Install a custom recovery(TWRP, CWM).
4. Flash the root software with the custom recovery.

For your phone there seem to have been changes in the root process. You can try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t50a8ivYLHw) video and report if you find any problem.